# Count form inputs using PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am attempting to look though the code for forms containing more than 3 input fields.  I cant seem to find a function to count only the inputs within a form tag without knowing the form id or class.  I have created the following code below to collect and loop through each form.

```
$forms = $this->html->find('form');
if(count($forms)>0){
    foreach($forms as $form){

    }
}
```

I have looked into the using $form->children() to count the children.  The issue is I would have to continue to look into childrens children to look for inputs.  Are there any other methods that would speed up counting the inputs within each form?

Comment: Instead of loosing your time with simple_html_dom, learn `DOMDocument`.

Comment: DOMDocument is not the best option if you are parsing HTML5. I dont like working with parsing systems that error on new code.

Comment: If you're looking for a HTML5  parser you could try [this one](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
$forms = $this->html->find('form');
foreach($forms as $form){
  if(count($form->find('input')) > 3) echo "Found one!";
}
```